# ssh: connect to host xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am unable to connect to bastion host in aws after accidentally deleting the openssh client in Ubuntu linux, even using the browser's connect mindterm won't let me hit the openssh-client button as well, does any one know how to solve this problem?

Note: the inbound security group has port 22 setup already, it all happens after I implement `apt-get purge openssh-client`, then it refuse to connect to make any fix.

Answer (score 0):

- Stop the ec2-instance
- In the EC2 console, under 'Actions' select 'View/Change User Data' give below command and power on the instance

  #!/bin/bash
   apt-get install -y openssh*

Comment: Assuming it's not a spot instance.

Comment: It solves my problem in a different way...the LinuxBastion instance automatically terminated and generate a new one. When I reconnect using ssh it shows "Host key verification failed." Implement `ssh-keygen -R hostname` makes me reconnect successfully, thank you!

Comment: i thought userdata is executed only once.